# MySQL OutFile to use data from table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to generate an export that runs monthly which appends a value from one of the columns within a table to the OutFile name, is this even possible?

The table is mytable and the column is col1 which contains "201601" at the minute

I would like my OutFile to show "/tmp/Output_201601" where the 201601 on next run will have automatically changed to 201602 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to do this with stored procedure.
Eg. when you call this procedure - it export data from table **mytable** to file with name **D:/tmp/Output_** + top value from field Col1.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `PrepareReport`()
BEGIN
 SET @OutputFileName := 'D://tmp//Output_';

 SELECT Col1 INTO @ReportNr FROM mytable ORDER BY Col1 DESC LIMIT 1;

 SET @q1 := concat("SELECT * FROM mytable INTO OUTFILE '", @OutputFileName, @ReportNr, ".csv'");
 PREPARE s1 FROM @q1;
 EXECUTE s1;
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE s1;
END
```